# Correct way of having loop end when required?

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, http, loop

I'm brand new to Arduinos. I'm currently trying to modify a script from [here](https://github.com/aaqib12/NodeMcu-Esp8266-Homebridge-Switch/blob/master/NODEMCU_CODE.ino) which at the moment, simply turns an LED on or off depending on which HTTP GET request it receives. However, I want to modify this to have the LED modulate on/off when presented with the On HTTP GET request and then simply turn off all together when presented with the Off HTTP GET request. However, I have two conflicting methods that I have found about how to achieve this; the first is:

```
int value = LOW;
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
      value = HIGH;
      do
      {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(5000);
      value = HIGH;
      } while (value = HIGH);
    }
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      value = LOW;
    }
```

Wheareas the other is:

```
  int value = LOW;
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
      value = HIGH;
      void loop() {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      delay(5000);
      value = HIGH;
      }
    }
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      value = LOW;
    }
```

As you can see, the first uses [do...while](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/dowhile/) and the second uses [loop()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/sketch/loop/). I have a feeling that the first of the two scripts would be more suitable as it should cut out as soon as `value` is set to `LOW` (i.e. when requested to turn off)

However, I would really appreciate it if someone could look through the two scripts and tell me which of the two is the correct way to achieve this sort of cut off when the HTTP GET Off is requested (if either for them even is the correct way to do this!).

Thank you in advance for your help,

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: Unfortunately they're both completely wrong. Use a state machine instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you for your response; that's a shame, how would I do that?

Comment: how does the `do...while` loop exit in the first snippet?

Comment: I assumed that when the off get request is made, you can see from the script that"value" is set to LOW and when this condition is met, the loop should exit

Comment: examine the example codes that are part of the Arduino IDE .... pay attention to the use of `setup()` and `loop()`   ....... have a very close look at the `flashWithoutDelay` sketch ..... in your program, set a flag when you receive an HTTP request ..... then in the code that follows the HTTP check, flash LED if flag is set .... turn off LED if flag is not set

Comment: also have a look at how the original code is formatted ... the indentation and the positioning of braces `{}` ..... then look at your code .... your code is badly formatted, so it is harder to read (hard to follow the program flow)

Comment: With the do...while `value` never changes to LOW, since the code that changes it is outside of the do...while and isn’t being run while value is HIGH. try moving the `int value...` outside the loop function (i.e. global variable), and removing the do...while (only leave the code inside it). Not sure if checking http requests only every 8 seconds will work.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for your response. That sounds like a great solution for this problem. I've had a look for that example sketch and couldn't find it. If it possible and if it is not too much to ask, would you please mind showing how I'd do this in an Answer format as I have very little programming experience with the Arduino IDE. Thank you

Comment: @Gerben Thank you for your comment. I understand the solution you are trying to suggest but I agree that I feel checking for a request every 8 seconds only will not work as the request itself would have to be made at exactly the right time. Any other solution you can think of?

Comment: The network stuff works in parallel to your code, so it might work.

Comment: @Gerben I'll give that a shot in a bit. Might it be better two have two separate loops going at the same time if that is even possible? I.e. one loop which is constantly ready for a new get request and another which can handle the do...while loop as the first loop is then free to change the "value" at any time which could stop the second loop if you see what I mean?

Comment: I don’t know if you can (simply) do multithreading on the ESP. a better solution is to do the blinking based on the millis value. That way you don’t need any delays. See the Arduino “blink without delay” page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and jsotola, you need to use a
state machine, like the one from the [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)
Arduino tutorial. Yours would be slightly more complicated because you
need a way to turn it on and off, and because you use different on and
off periods. Here is an example code that abstract the blinking logic
into three functions:

- `update_led()` takes care of the blinking, and it has to be called
  quite often in order to achieve a smooth blinking
- `start_blinking()` and `stop_blinking()`, as their names suggest, are
  used to turn the blinking state machine on and off.

```c++
const uint32_t ON_TIME  = 3000;
const uint32_t OFF_TIME = 5000;

bool led_blinking;     // are we blinking the LED?
bool led_on;           // is the LED currently on?
uint32_t last_toggle;  // last time it toggled while blinking

void update_led() {
    if (!led_blinking) return;
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (led_on && now - last_toggle >= ON_TIME) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        led_on = false;
        last_toggle = now;
    }
    if (!led_on && now - last_toggle >= OFF_TIME) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        led_on = true;
        last_toggle = now;
    }
}

void start_blinking() {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    led_blinking = true;
    led_on = true;
    last_toggle = millis();
}

void stop_blinking() {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    led_blinking = false;
    led_on = false;
}
```

You then have to call these functions from `loop()` as follows:

```c++
void loop() {
    // Keep the LED blinking if necessary.
    update_led();
    ...
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
        start_blinking();
    }
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
        stop_blinking();
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit**, in response to jsotola’s comments:

When answering the question, I was initially tempted to make a
`BlinkingLed` class, with the functions as its public interface and the
variables private. I resisted the temptation on the grounds that, given
the apparent OP’s level of C++ knowledge, that could end up being well
over his head. Instead, I used documentation as an informal way of
separating the public from the private: you are only supposed to use
what is documented, i.e. the functions. You don't “take a shortcut in
your program and clear `led_blinking` directly”.

You could, of course, make the `led_blinking` variable part of the
public interface. That could even be a nice simplification, as you don't
need the start/stop function anymore. But then you loose control over
the initial phase of the blinking pattern. That may not be an issue, but
if you want the LED to turn on as soon as you set `led_blinking` to
`true`, then you have to do something like

```c++
void update_led() {
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (!led_blinking) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        led_on = false;
        last_toggle = now - OFF_TIME;  // fix initial phase
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that the subtraction can overflow, but that's not as issue because
it follows the rules of modular arithmetics.

I actually kind of like this option, with all the logic in a single
function. This way the variables `led_on` and `last_toggle` can be made
static local to the function, which provides true encapsulation without
a class. However, from a pedagogic point of view, I think my initial
proposal is easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate all the help that people have supplied me with in the comments but I really appreciate the fact that you have been able to break down the problem into understandable chunks and provide a well structured answer. Thank you!

Comment: change this line `if (!led_blinking) return;`  so that it turns off the LED and then returns

Comment: @jsotola I'm confused as to what you mean. Are you saying that this line he has written is incorrect? If so, what should the line read?

Comment: no, i am not saying that it was written wrong ... the LED will certainly stop blinking when `led_blinking==false` ..... if `led_blinking` is cleared (set to false) by the `stop_blinking()` function, then the LED will be off ..... however, if you take a shortcut in your program and clear `led_blinking` directly without calling `stop_blinking()`, then the LED will stop blinking, but it may be on

Comment: @jsotala Ah, I see, that makes sense. How exactly would I adapt that code to have it that when `led_blinking==false`, the led will turn off completely even if currently on? Would you be able to post some code which may help fix this problem? Thank you very much :)

Comment: i do not understand why you are asking for code .... you already have the `if (!led_blinking)` line given to you by Edgar Bonet ... and you have previously written the turnoff code in what you posted .... look at the second `if` statement .... just insert the code for turning off the LED before the `return` command

Comment: @jsotola: I am responding to your comments in an edit to my answer.